# `require': cannot load such file -- rainbow (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to run rubocop for my rails app but I am getting this error: -

Rails version - 6.0.2.2
Ruby Version - 2.6.3

````
    9: from /Users/satyam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
    8: from /Users/satyam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
    7: from /Users/satyam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/rubocop:23:in `<main>'
    6: from /Users/satyam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/rubocop:23:in `load'
    5: from /Users/satyam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rubocop-0.81.0/exe/rubocop:6:in `<top (required)>'
    4: from /Users/satyam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    3: from /Users/satyam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    2: from /Users/satyam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rubocop-0.81.0/lib/rubocop.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    1: from /Users/satyam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/satyam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- rainbow (LoadError)```
````

Comment: It appears rubocop wants another gem named ‘rainbow’ to be installed. If you’re using bundler, try ‘bundle install’, if not, ‘gem install rainbow’

Comment: Yup it works! I had to gem install ruby-progressbar after this though. Thanks! :)